# Bigquery unnest a string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I spent too much time on this why this does not work, if I remove replace it works fine

```
 SELECT
  * from unnest( [  "'"||replace('POINT(153.07081 -27.498136), POINT(153.076338 -27.47167)' ,", ","', '")||"'" ]) as element
```

Comment: You should perhaps explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your purpose is to split the string `'POINT(153.07081 -27.498136), POINT(153.076338 -27.47167)', ', ')'` into two rows, one for each point, then I would expect:

```
SELECT * 
FROM unnest(split('POINT(153.07081 -27.498136), POINT(153.076338 -27.47167)', ', '
                 )
           ) element
```

Comment: you are a boss !!